# First start of App CameraSurface crashes. After submitting Permission it works

Tags: android, permissions, android-camera2

I have a App which creates a TextureView with the Camera attached to it. At the Moment, the Activity is also the MainLauncher of the Application.
I wanted to use the new Permission Style just as intended and called the Permission when the Camera should be in use. But when I start the App for the first Time, it calls my Permission, I accept it, and after that the App crashes (*Only Information in Logcat is SIG:9*). When I start it again (because I already submitted) it works fine. Did I set the call for the Permission at the wrong place? (*btw. I call multiple Permissions, because I also start to create a Image Gallery*). I could't find similar Questions so I wanted to ask the Question now.

Here is my Code:

OnCreate:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    callPermissions(); // calls multiple Permissions.

    setContentView(R.layout.camera_landscape);

    mCaptureButton = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.photoButton);
    mCalcButton = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.descriptor);
    mTrackButton = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.track);

    mTextureView = (AutoTextureView) findViewById(R.id.texture);
}
```

callPermissions:

```
private void callPermissions(){
    List<String> permissionsNeeded = new ArrayList<String>();

    final List<String> permissionsList = new ArrayList<String>();
    if(!addPermission(permissionsList, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE))
        permissionsNeeded.add("WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE");
    if(!addPermission(permissionsList, Manifest.permission.CAMERA))
        permissionsNeeded.add("CAMERA");

    if(permissionsList.size()> 0){
        if(permissionsNeeded.size() > 0){
            String message = "You need to grant access to " + permissionsNeeded.get(0);
            for(int i = 1; i < permissionsNeeded.size(); i++)
                message = message + ", " + permissionsNeeded.get(i);

            showMessageOKCancel(message,
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(CameraTest.this, permissionsList.toArray(new String[permissionsList.size()]),
                                    REQUEST_CODE_ALL_PERMISSIONS);
                        }
                    });
            return;
        }
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(CameraTest.this, permissionsList.toArray(new String[permissionsList.size()]),
                REQUEST_CODE_ALL_PERMISSIONS);
    }
}
```

And the Overriden onRequestPermissionResult:

```
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults){
    switch(requestCode){
        case REQUEST_CAMERA_PERMISSION:
            if(grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
                openCamera();
            }else{
                Toast.makeText(CameraTest.this, "CAMERA access Denied", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            break;
        case REQUEST_CODE_ALL_PERMISSIONS:{
            Map<String, Integer> perms = new HashMap<String, Integer>();

            perms.put(Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED);
            perms.put(Manifest.permission.CAMERA, PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED);

            for(int i = 0; i < permissions.length; i++)
                perms.put(permissions[i], grantResults[i]);

            if(perms.get(Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED &&
                    perms.get(Manifest.permission.CAMERA) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){

            }else{
                //Permissions Denied
                Toast.makeText(CameraTest.this, "Some Permission is Denied", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
        default:
            super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    }
}
```

And Here the LogCat output:

```
10-25 10:56:56.906 26719-26719/? I/art: Late-enabling -Xcheck:jni
10-25 10:56:56.926 26719-26725/? I/art: Debugger is no longer active
10-25 10:56:57.084 26719-26743/? D/OpenGLRenderer: Use EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED: true
10-25 10:56:57.163 26719-26743/? I/Adreno-EGL: <qeglDrvAPI_eglInitialize:379>: QUALCOMM Build: 10/21/15, 369a2ea, I96aee987eb
10-25 10:56:57.172 26719-26743/? I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
10-25 10:56:57.331 26719-26719/? I/CameraManagerGlobal: Connecting to camera service
10-25 10:57:02.407 26719-26719/com.example.camera D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
10-25 10:57:02.408 26719-26866/com.example.camera I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 26719 SIG: 9
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I could solve the Solution by myself, 
I Also have a Method (which I totally missed to add) Which is called `openCamera` Which configures the Camera for the TextureSurface:

```
private void openCamera() {
    CameraManager cameraManager = (CameraManager) getSystemService(Context.CAMERA_SERVICE);
    try {
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.CAMERA) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            if(!ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(CameraTest.this, Manifest.permission.CAMERA)){
                //showMessageOKCancel("You need to allow access to Camera", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){
                //    @Override
                //    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which){
                //        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(CameraTest.this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.CAMERA}, REQUEST_CAMERA_PERMISSION);
                //    }
                //});
                return;
            }
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(CameraTest.this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.CAMERA}, REQUEST_CAMERA_PERMISSION);
            return;
        }
        cameraManager.openCamera(mCameraId, mDeviceCallback, mBackgroundHandler);
    }catch(CameraAccessException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

There, I also started a Dialog, when the User has not granted the Permission yet. After I commented the showMessageOkCancel Method (which creates the dialog) everything works fine and only my `callPermissions` method requests my two Permissions and the Application does not crash at the first start.